# Adb connection Error EOF + Sending jdwp tracking request failed

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

In eclipse(latest version) when running my android project i get this DDMS error again and again:

Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-03-06 11:44:58 - DeviceMonitor] Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

I have tried about everything
Killed the adb server, reseting it, cleaned the project, restarted, chmoded the file permissions to ddms and android files in the tools folder

Its driving me nuts...

My platform is mac osx ver:10.9.1

/Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you recently update to either Eclipse adt 22.3 or Eclipse adt 22.6?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late comment, the flu got me. I have been using the latest adt bundle..